# Difference between the "const" and "final" in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

If I declare that in Dart : `final Color _iconColor = Color.fromARGB(210, 198, 15, 1`, Vs Code
display this message :
*Prefer const with constant constructors.*

So the result is :
`final Color _iconColor = const Color.fromARGB(210, 198, 15, 1);`. And VsCode is good.

But if my variable _iconColor is already final, why add const inside ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`const` and `final` are not the same.

`const` means that the value is known at compile time, whereas `final` means that the variable is immutable after being set.

From Flutter best practices [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/perf/best-practices):

> Use const constructors on widgets as much as possible, since they
> allow Flutter to short-circuit most of the rebuild work

Using `const` keyword everytime it's possible will increase your performances, since Flutter won't have to re-build const widgets.

In your case, you define your `_iconColor` as `final`, which means that you won't be able to modify it afterwards. And you set it to a `const` value, known at compile time.